# How to use the model(decision tree) in C/C++ which trained in R?

Tags: c++, r, decision-tree

we have a C++ system, and what I meant is how to integrate the model in our system?

I use R to train a decision tree model, print the tree like this:

```
     Conditional inference tree with 47 terminal nodes

Response:  label 
Inputs:  term_num, res_num, r0_pv_num, r0_dr, r0_tr, r0_qr, r0_cr, r0_td, r0_hit_tn, r0_hit_tidf, r0_hit_cidf, r0_hit_tnr, r0_tidfr, r0_cidfr, r0_fr, r1_pv_num, r1_dr, r1_tr, r1_qr, r1_cr, r1_td, r1_hit_tn, r1_hit_tidf, r1_hit_cidf, r1_hit_tnr, r1_tidfr, r1_cidfr, r1_fr, r2_pv_num, r2_dr, r2_tr, r2_qr, r2_cr, r2_td, r2_hit_tn, r2_hit_tidf, r2_hit_cidf, r2_hit_tnr, r2_tidfr, r2_cidfr, r2_fr, r3_pv_num, r3_dr, r3_tr, r3_qr, r3_cr, r3_td, r3_hit_tn, r3_hit_tidf, r3_hit_cidf, r3_hit_tnr, r3_tidfr, r3_cidfr, r3_fr 
Number of observations:  9944 

1) r3_fr <= 910; criterion = 1, statistic = 2800.604
  2) r1_tr <= 12; criterion = 1, statistic = 375.037
    3) r3_dr <= 4; criterion = 1, statistic = 107.044
      4) r0_tidfr <= 0.65; criterion = 1, statistic = 52.212
        5) r0_tr <= 0; criterion = 0.999, statistic = 19.047
          6)*  weights = 358 
        5) r0_tr > 0
          7) term_num <= 4; criterion = 0.994, statistic = 14.917
            8) r3_fr <= 496; criterion = 1, statistic = 20.334
              9)*  weights = 149 
            8) r3_fr > 496
              10)*  weights = 140 
          7) term_num > 4
            11)*  weights = 825 
      4) r0_tidfr > 0.65
        12)*  weights = 190 
    3) r3_dr > 4
      13) term_num <= 4; criterion = 1, statistic = 43.327
        14) r3_fr <= 613; criterion = 1, statistic = 37.962
          15)*  weights = 33 
        14) r3_fr > 613
          16)*  weights = 225
etc...
```

How can I transplant this model into my C/C++ system？（And it's no terminal node in the print）.Thanks!

Comment: Your question is very broad right now, so the only answer you'll get is an equally broad answer (see my answer below). We have no details regarding the R code, we have no details regarding the C++ code, etc. To get a more specific answer, you need to provide much more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the following steps:

1. Find out what the interface is of your C++ system, i.e. what inputs does it need, and in which form, to be able to run the decision tree.
2. Interface with your C++ code in the way defined in step 1. This can either be done in memory, or using files on disk.
3. Run the decision tree.

In this context, the `Rcpp` R package might be an interesting package to look at. It facilitates running C++ code from within R.

Comment: Oh, we have a C++ system, and what I meant is how to integrate the model in our system.

Comment: We do not have your C++ system, so we do not know how to integrate the R decision tree into your C++ system. In general, the tips I already gave apply. Find out what the interface is to your C++ system, and dump the R outcome in such a way that the C++ code can work with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But suppose I got a decision tree in R, and then I need to write a C++ aplication to test this model, i.e. give an input, read data, invoke decision tree function, and output the prediction. What can I do it?